# Iterate though rows in a dataframe to find index, values in a column in jupyter and print the report in csvfile

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to check if there are any values in Column 'Weight' that are less than 90. If yes, I would like to store the index and values in a variable, so I can print it out in csvfile. I used the following code but I am getting wrong output.Please help.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Weight'] < 90:
       result = index, row['Weight']

res = [result]
csvfile = "<Report>"

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n''\n')
    for val in res:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

Comment: Don't iterate, use `loc` based selection with vectorized boolean operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispense with the for-loop (this should be your last resort in `pandas`), instead:

```
df.loc[df.Weight < 90, 'Weight'].to_csv(csvfile)
```

Is all you should need.

Note, your original approach, while not optimal, *would have worked* if you had used a list:

```
result = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Weight'] < 90:
       result.append((index, row['Weight']))
```

Then simply remove this line:

<strike>`res = [result]`</strike>

And also change

```
writer.writerow([val])
```

To

```
writer.writerow(val)
```

Or even more simply, don't loop over result and use `.writerows`:

```
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='')
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Finally, with `csv.writer`, you should always use `lineterminator=''`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! the code worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

This can likely be done much more succinctly using built in Pandas functions. Something like:

```
output = df[df['Weight'] < 90]
output.to_csv(csvfile)
```

See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for more options relating to writing a DataFrame to a CSV.